# Drag UITableView or all TableViewCells to display a label

Tags: swift, timestamp, label, tableview

I'd like to create make a table view go to left when we swipe with a pan gesture. The goal is to display a label a the right of the table view like Instagram or iMessage for instance. Does anyone have a tip for creating this?

The result I would like to get.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDdSa.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rough sketch, you may place a subview containing a timestamp inside your cell, below or to the side of the main subviews that display the content. You also will need to write a method that, depending on the pan progression, will show/hide this timestamp. Then you add a pan gesture recognizer to the table view itself, and, once panning, in your handler method you can call this disclosure method on the visible cells.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So you really recommend to use a collection view. Just to be accurate, I have to set a collection view with only 1 item, and put the table view in. After, that I can make the table view like 50 px wider than the view so that when I detect a pan gesture, I can show the timestamp?

Comment: Now I actually think that a collection view would be an overshoot. You can definitely achieve your goal by just using a table view; I've edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Don't you think that is there any way for drag all cells by using the editing row methods for table views?

Comment: Row editing methods present very standard UI (you can find many tutorials on this to have an example how it will look) — that is, this will not help you with your task (and even more generally, what you are trying to do is semantically far away from editing, so even if you "hack" these methods to do what you want, it is a rather confusing practice).

You will need to write your *own* methods within your cell subclass to change the appearance of the cell (i.e., move everything to the left while disclosing a timestamp label, which you also add yourself, since it will be a custom element).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will try to apply it

Comment: If you generally do not yet understand how to manipulate the layout of any view (including cells), I'd suggest you first try experimenting with adding a gesture recognizer to something and then changing it's `frame`, for example, to react to the movement of the recognizer. Once you are comfortable with this, it will be much easier for you to reason about creating custom UI interactions.